# Solution verification: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{9^n}{3+10^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, solution-verification

I need to find out whether

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{9^n}{3+10^n}$$

converges or diverges using the limit comparison test. Here's my work:

Let $a_n$ be $\frac{9^n}{3+10^n}$, $b_n$ be $\frac{1}{10^n}$.

\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
&\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} \\
&\implies \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{9^n}{3+10^n}}{\frac{1}{10^n}} \\
&\implies \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{9^n \cdot 10^n}{3+10^n}\\
&\implies \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{9^n \cdot \cancel{10^n}}{\cancel{10^n}\cdot(\frac{3}{10^n} + 1)}
\end{align}

Then here, we have that the numerator goes to infinity while the bottom becomes one so the limit itself goes to infinity and therefore, the sum is divergent by comparison test.

Is this correct?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure that is what the limit comparison test says?

Comment: when $b_n=\frac{1}{10^n} $ $b_n \leq a_n $

Comment: @Anonymous Ahhhh! It's gotta be $a_n \le b_n$ yes?

Comment: You wanna construct a $b_n$ such that $a_n \leq b_n$ .

Comment: I'm not sure it matters if one sequence is greater than the other for limit comparison. You just need the limit of their ratio to be finite nonzero correct? Then both converge or diverge. So if you are trying to show convergence you should just choose a $b_n$ that you know converges. The problem with your original choice is that the limit diverged so the LCT gives you nothing.

Comment: @Ebearr Hmm okay. So, we must choose $b_n$ such that the limit does not diverge but produces a finite value right? And my choice, produces a limit which moves toward infinite which means nothing with respect to the LCT, right?

Comment: @JeelShah Exactly. To satisfy the hypotheses of the LCT, the limit must be finite nonzero. So if you do not have that, then you can say nothing from the LCT. Your choice went to infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** A good choice is rather $$b_n=\left(\frac 9{10}\right)^n$$ giving
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=1
$$ and giving **the convergence of the initial series**.

Comment: Does choosing $b_n$ simply come from experience or is there some logic behind it? and also, what is wrong with my choice? Which is to say, how do I know that I have the wrong choice?

Comment: Some experience (and logic:)), here, as $n \to \infty$: $$ \frac{9^n}{3+10^n}=\frac{9^n}{10^n}\times\frac{1}{1+3/10^n}\sim \left(\frac 9{10}\right)^n $$ Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Choose $ b_n=(\frac {9}{10})^n$

now look that $ a_n \leq b_n\forall n \in N$

our $ b_n $ is a GP Now try by yourself

Answer (score 0):

$$0\leq \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{9^n}{3+10^n}\leq \sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^n = 9 $$
so the series is convergent. Namely,
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{9^n}{3+10^n} &=& \sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^n-3\left(\frac{9}{100}\right)^n+3^2\left(\frac{9}{1000}\right)^n-\ldots\right)\\&=&9-\frac{3\cdot 9}{91}+\frac{9\cdot 9}{991}-\frac{27\cdot 9}{9991}+\ldots\\&=&9\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^m 3^m}{10^{m+1}-9}=\color{red}{8.7663187635381\ldots}\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Nice proof! Now would that be a transcendental number...?

Comment: @hypergeometric: nice question. I would bet on "yes", but we need to accelerate even more the series representation to be able to state that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't conclude a series diverges by comparing it to $\sum_1^\infty\frac{1}{10^n}$ because that series converges. Try comparing it to $(9/10)^n$ and conclude it converges